# How to set Textbox value at page load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to set asp.net TextBox’s value at page load using JQuery.
Can somebody give me example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#TextBox1").val("Hello World");
            });
</script>
```

Comment: I have accepted his answer because he has given answer before any one else. All other answer is almost copy of his answer.

Comment: If you are using an HTML textbox this is the correct answer.  If you were trying to do an ASP.NET textbox then this will not work.

Comment: For an ASP.NET TextBox that has the ID `TextBox1`? `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ....`

Answer (score 2):

If it is an ASP.NET TextBox Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#<%= tb_ASPTextBox.ClientID %>').val("my value"); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Example http://fiddle.jshell.net/UB5L9/